# Firebase authentication with password less type crashing app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have integrated `FirebaseAuth` in my app to log in or signup users through password-less authentication.

I have done all the setup mention on `Firebase` docs.

Also, I followed the below blog to set up firebase password-less authentication.

https://medium.com/@huzaifa.ameen229/firebase-email-link-authentication-ac2504068562

Below is my code of `sendAuthLink` where it suppose to send a link to mention mail id but somehow it's crashing with the below crash logs.

**Code:**

```
@IBAction func didTapSendSignInLink(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = self.emailField.text {
            let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.init()
            actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
            actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: String(format:"https://myapp-4e836.firebaseapp.com/?email=%@",email))
            actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
            
            Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail:email,actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings) { error in
                                        // ...
                                        if let error = error {
                                            print("error in send link :",error)
                                            //self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                                            return
                                        }
                                        // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
                                        // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
                                        // if they open the link on the same device.
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "Email")
                                        //self.showMessagePrompt("Check your email for link")
                                        // ...
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

**Crash Log:**

> -[SignUpInVC sendAuthLink:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106e0fa30 2019-03-01 11:25:36.700059+0530 Marty[12426:2747193] ***
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SignUpInVC sendAuthLink:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106e0fa30'

I am not sure if I miss something in the setup if anyone facing this issue.

I never call `[SignUpInVC sendAuthLink:]` function but still, it's throwing a crash with an above log.

Please guide me to get it working without crash my app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your shown code is not relevant code of crash `[SignUpInVC sendAuthLink:]`

Comment: ya that is the problem I have never used `sendAuthLink` function in my `SignUpInVC` controller but still its throwing crash with this log strange issue.

Comment: ensure once are you copied or used the target of your button action `didTapSendSignInLink` from signup and signin page also]

Comment: ohh what a silly mistake i have made. Thanks for the help its action issue connected via storyboard.

Comment: good , happy to hear.